# Specs for MOV op-codes

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, machine-code

In all the documentation I can find regarding op-codes for MOV mnemonic, each op-code is not documented individually. op-code `B8h+` Is documented as moving 16- or 32-bit data to a 16- or 32-bit registry. What registry exactly is concerned, is determined by how far above `B8h` the op-code is. That is to say, to get the op-code for a MOV instruction of `B8h` type, you take `B8h` and add the number of the register. Problem is, I don't find any information about the number of each registry. The following is my guess, but I am not sure.

Destination registry. Op-code.

```
AX  B8

CX  B9

DX  BA

BX  BB

EAX BC

ECX BD

EDX BE

EBX BF
```

Answer (score 7):

You have an error in your table: 16 and 32bit operand size have the same opcode, and are differentiated by an operand-size prefix byte to use the one that's not currently the default operand size.  (So 16bit instructions take an extra byte in 32bit and 64bit mode.)  This is true for all opcodes, not just `mov`.

You could have checked this yourself with an assembler, and a disassembler that includes the hex bytes of the instruction encoding in the output.

There are separate opcodes for 8 vs. 16/32/64 for most instructions, but I guess there wasn't enough opcode space to add another version of everything when the extension from 16 to 32bit happened.

- `mov r8, imm8` uses the opcode `B0+rb` (so, B0-B7).
- `mov r16/32/64, imm16/32/64` uses the opcode `B8+rw/rd` (so, B8-BF), with either an operand-size prefix, a REX prefix with the .W bit set), or no prefix.

Since we're on the topic, it's worth mentioning that `mov r/m64, imm32` (sign-extended move-immediate) has to use an extra byte to encode the destination register or effective address, but is still shorter than `mov r64, imm64`.  In AT&T syntax, you have to use the `movabs` mnemonic if you want it, otherwise the assembler truncates your constant to 32bits.

---

The actual binary encodings for register numbers appears to be specified in three places in Intel's ref manuals, Volume 2.  (linked from the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki).

Most relevant to this question (register encoded as the last 3 bits of the opcode), there's *Table 3-1. Register Codes Associated With +rb, +rw, +rd, +ro*, inside *Section 3.1: INTERPRETING THE INSTRUCTION REFERENCE PAGES*.

The encodings are the same as in Appendix B.1.3, which again points out that the 3-bit register field can be the last 3 bits of the opcode.  (I guess all the opcodes that use `+rb` / `+rd` are multiples of 8, so adding 0-7 = setting the last 3 bits).  B.1.4.1 has tables of which register each possible 3-bit value selects, for 16bit and 32bit operand-sizes (in non-64bit mode).

It goes:

```
encoding | 8bit reg | 32bit reg 
000  |       AL   |      EAX
001  |       CL   |      ECX
010  |       DL   |      EDX
011  |       BL   |      EBX
100  |       AH   |      ESP
101  |       CH   |      EBP
110  |       DH   |      ESI
111  |       BH   |      EDI
```

Tables for other operand sizes, and for 64bit mode, are nearby.  (Instructions with a REX prefix normally can't address AH/BH/CH/DH, only the low-byte of the 16 GP registers.  I guess this is because the encoding for `ch` collides with `bpl`, when used with a REX prefix.)

---

There's also a table of register encodings (for using in mod/rm fields) in chapter 2, with tables.

There's also a mention of encoding the dest register into the opcode, in the section for 64bit mode, after the tables.

Chapter 2.2.1.1: Encoding  (inside the IA-32e section):

> Intel 64 and IA-32 instruction formats specify up to three registers
>   by using 3-bit fields in the encoding, depending on the format:
>
> - ModR/M: the reg and r/m fields of the ModR/M byte
> - ModR/M with SIB: the reg field of the ModR/M byte, the base and index fields of the SIB (scale, index, base) byte
> - Instructions without ModR/M: the reg field of the opcode

Comment: But if a certain value is used to indicate another data-size than the current one, what if you want to use that same value as an operand?

Comment: And how is the current data-size (16-/32-bit) determined? Is it hardcoded in the processor, or can it be changed using a specific mnemonic?

Comment: @user504882: If you want 16bit operand size in 16bit mode, you omit the operand-size prefix byte (`66h`).  The current default operand size is a mode the CPU can be in.  e.g. real mode is 16bit, protected mode is 32bit.  Or something like that.  I don't think there's a way to change the default operand size without privileged instructions to change the CPU's operation mode.

Comment: In "B8+rw/rd", are rw and rd representing the number of the register to use? Is the prefix occuring right before or after the op-code? You are saying a certain bit must be set in the prefix? I thought all 16 bits must be either set or not set according to a certain pattern, in order to be recognized as a prefix?

Comment: Look at some disassembler output, like `objdump -Mintel -d a.out`.  Opcode prefix *bytes* are whole bytes that modify the following opcode.  And yes, `rw` or `rd` are 3-bit fields where the register number goes.  Your question was only asking about where register-encodings inside opcodes was documented.  It sounds like you need to google up a tutorial / guide on x86 machine code.

Comment: Your answers have been helpful. Perhaps you can answer a similar question while we're at it. I find the documentation for MOV op-code `8Bh` very confusing: "8B / r       MOV r16,r/m16      Move r/m16 to r16". In this case, the three bits are not used to indicate the register concerned, so how does it work in this case?

Comment: @user504882: It works the same as most other instructions, with a `/r` byte after the opcode encoding the destination effective address (or register), and the source register.  This can require more bytes, depending on addressing mode.  It's all right there in the Intel manuals I pointed you at, right next to the sections I quoted.  Also, `8B / r MOV r16,r/m16`  "Move r/m16 to r16" would have been *way* more readable.  You can use backticks in comments...